# Print pages in a worksheet based on a value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro that will print pages from 1 to "cell value a1". A1 = members in different organizations.

I need to print page 1 and 2, but from page 3 on so on. If there is only 1 member in the organization, i just need the three pages. If there is is 10 members I also just need 3 pages, but for every 11, 21, 31 members and so on, i need to print one extra page.

The value in A1 will be 3(pages) if its 10 or less members, 4 if its 11-20 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using VBA to set the `Worksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea` property and also setting appropriate page breaks using `Worksheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=rowRef` where `rowRef="A11"` etc.

Comment: Have a go at this and if you can't it to work, post your attempt in the question and I'll try and work it out for your specific case

Comment: Hmm...not sure I understood that, but thanks!

Is it possible to use this?

Worksheets.PrintOut from:=1, to:=3

Where the last number(3) can come from A1? How do I do that?